# Feed source command with a pipe

Tags: shell, pipe

Previously I used `source` command like this:

```
source file_name
```

But what I'm trying to do is this:

```
echo something | source
```

Which doesn't work.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Since `source` (or `.`) takes a file as argument, you could try process substitution:

```
source <(echo something)
```

Comment: That worked, thank you. And Happy New Year!

Comment: @muru This works great. Note that "| source /dev/stdin" has the *appearance* of working, but it'll actually drop all of the variable assignments. Not sure why. Seems solid in theory. It's insanity.

Comment: @DustinOprea pipes create a subshell, so all those variable assignments never affect the parent shell.

Comment: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/SubShell

Comment: Works in Bash: source /dev/stdin <<< "echo 123; X=42; echo 456"; echo $X

Comment: The question is not about a specific shell so it is important to say that the process substitution `<(command ...)` is not part of the POSIX specification. You can find it in ksh, bash and some other shells. See [What is the portable (POSIX) way to achieve process substitution?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/309547/19702).

Comment: @pabouk-Ukrainestaystrong eh... did you miss that `source` isn't part of the POSIX specification either?

Comment: That makes it even worse :D The `.` command is part of POSIX and `source` is just a more readable alias for it. See https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#dot

Comment: @pabouk-Ukrainestaystrong I'm not sure how it makes it worse, since `source` is explicitly in the question, so this question at least isn't about POSIX shells

Comment: I wonder why `sudo cat /root/.bashrc | bash` didn't work. But your command worked perfectly.

Answer (score 11):

Your source command requires a file argument. You can get that in some shells with a process substitution, and this is because in the same way the shell replaces...

```
arg=$(echo hi)
```

...the `echo` bit there on the command-line with the subshell's output, in the case of process substitution it replaces the subshell with a named file - usually `/dev/fd/62` or something - some link to a file-descriptor. With a pipe the file descriptor is 0 so...

```
echo 'echo hi' | . /dev/fd/0
```

... `/dev/stdin` or whatever as the case may be should work just fine on any linux system - and many others besides. You can also use here-documents similarly:

```
. /dev/fd/3 3<<HI
$(echo 'echo hi')
HI
```

You can verify the way your shell handles process substitution, by the way:

```
(set -x; readlink <(:))
```

...which prints *(in `bash`)*:

```
+ set +x
+ readlink /dev/fd/63
++ :
pipe:[2212581]
```

...and so we can see that the shell is doing the substitution and `readlink` is reading from an an anoymous pipe that it opens on file-descriptor 63.

Comment: You cannot use a process in a pipe (your example `echo 'echo hi' | . /dev/fd/0`) to make side-effects in the current shell (like setting aliases, environment etc.) because the commands in a pipe are run as child processes and their side-effect are lost when they are finished.