# How to set multiple env variables from stdout pipe

Tags: bash, shell-script, environment-variables

I have a bunch of piped shell commands that give some env output. I want to set these as env variables for an additional command to add to the chain

```
Kevins-MBP:ops kevzettler$ eb printenv | tail -n +2 | sed "s/ //g"
NODE_ENV=staging
RDSPassword=changme
RDSHost=sa1c7quehy7pes5.lolol.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
RDSUsername=derp
```

Comment: Also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/176873/117549

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want:

```
source <(eb printenv | tail -n +2 | sed 's/ //g; s/^/export /')
your_next_command_that_uses_those_env_vars
```

---

A test:

- define a function that prints out your sample variable definitions

  ```
  function eb {
  echo "
  NODE_ENV=staging
  RDSPassword=changme
  RDSHost=sa1c7quehy7pes5.lolol.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
  RDSUsername=derp"
  }
  ```
- call it to see what the pipeline produces

  ```
  $ eb printenv | tail -n +2 | sed 's/ //g; s/^/export /'
  export NODE_ENV=staging
  export RDSPassword=changme
  export RDSHost=sa1c7quehy7pes5.lolol.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
  export RDSUsername=derp
  ```
- source that output, test the current shell and a new shell to see if it's exported

  ```
  $ source <(eb printenv | tail -n +2 | sed 's/ //g; s/^/export /')
  $ echo $NODE_ENV
  staging
  $ sh -c 'echo $NODE_ENV'
  staging
  ```

Comment: Doesn't work. `source <(eb printenv | tail -n +2 | sed "s/ //g"); echo $NODE_ENV` gives me no output

Comment: "works for me" (TM) -- break your pipeline down command by command to see where it breaks down.

Comment: @kevzettler, you missed trailing sed command argument, substitutng beginning of each line with `export`, glenn jackmann's example does have it.  It makes all your var assignments prepended with `export` directive, which is important

Comment: @Tagwint he updated the post after I made that comment with the `export` directives