# How to print multi-line variables in side-by-side columns in sh?

Tags: bash, shell, text-processing, columns, paste

This question is based on [a similar question on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1066404/1069309),
but instead of `bash`, I would like to have similar output in `sh`.

No issue in bash; it works as expected.

```
wolf@linux:~$ echo $SHELL
/usr/bin/bash
wolf@linux:~$ 
wolf@linux:~$ varA='Aug 01
> Aug 16
> Aug 26'
wolf@linux:~$ 
wolf@linux:~$ varB='04:25
> 03:39
> 10:06'
wolf@linux:~$ 
wolf@linux:~$ echo "$varA $varB"
Aug 01
Aug 16
Aug 26 04:25
03:39
10:06
wolf@linux:~$
wolf@linux:~$ paste <(printf %s "$varA") <(printf %s "$varB")
Aug 01  04:25
Aug 16  03:39
Aug 26  10:06
wolf@linux:~$
```

However, when I try similar command in `sh`, I'm getting the following error.

```
wolf@linux:~$ sh
$ 
$ varA='Aug 01
> Aug 16
> Aug 26'

$ varB='04:25
> 03:39
> 10:06'
$ 
$ echo "$varA $varB"
Aug 01
Aug 16
Aug 26 04:25
03:39
10:06
$ 
$ paste <(printf %s "$varA") <(printf %s "$varB")
sh: 22: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
$
```

Is it possible to get similar output in `sh`?

Comment: *echo -e "$varA\t$varB" | paste*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40428994

Comment: `<( ... )` is a bash construct not available in sh

Comment: Related: [What is the portable (POSIX) way to achieve process substitution?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/309547)

Answer (score 6):

**If your variables have the same number of lines** then you could use the `pr` command to print standard output into two columns ex.

```
$ printf '%s\n' "$varA" "$varB" | pr -2 -Ts^I       
Aug 01  04:25
Aug 16  03:39
Aug 26  10:06
```

where `^I` stands for the TAB character (to be consistent with the default separator of the `paste` command) and may be introduced using key combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>TAB</kbd>, while `-T` turns off headers and footers.

Comment: If your shell is bash, you can write `-s $'\t'`

Answer (score 1):

You could always use `mktemp` but it's not specified by POSIX and
there are some race conditions associated with it.

You can always use a while loop like that but remember that loops in
shell are very slow:

```
counter=1
while true
do
    left="$(echo "$varA" | awk -v cnt="$counter" 'NR==cnt {printf $0}')"
    right="$(echo "$varB" | awk -v cnt="$counter" 'NR==cnt {printf $0}')"
    if [ -z "$left" ] && [ -z "$right" ]
    then
        break
    fi

    echo "$left $right"
    counter=$((counter + 1))
done
```

Output:

```
Aug 01 04:25
Aug 16 03:39
Aug 26 10:06
```

You can add more variables if you need to but it'll not satisfy the
*should work for a dynamic number of variables* requirement because
you have to add them manually. And you can of course implement
everything within awk.

Comment: (1) The question says “… in side-by-side ***columns*** …”. And, no, it doesn’t explicitly define the term “columns”. But you seem to assume that each variable consists of a sequence of strings that are the same length. If that assumption is not true, this answer fails to satisfy the meaning that would be assumed by an ordinary English interpretation of the word “columns”. (2) Also, this solution can exhibit undesired behavior if the variables include blank lines. (3) If you know how to implement everything within awk, why not show such an answer?

Answer (score 1):

The bounty notice says

> The answer should work on all shells,
> for variables that do not have the same number of lines,
> and should work for a dynamic number of variables

“work on all shells”, strictly speaking, is impossible. 
It’s just about impossible to do *anything* non-trivial
that works in C shell-family shells
and also Bourne shell / POSIX-family shells. 
I have tested the following in bash,
dash (which is a fairly rudimentary POSIX-compliant shell), ash and zsh.

Here are a few ways to set multi-line variables:

```
var17='The
quick
brown
fox'

var42=`echo jumps; echo over; echo -e 'the\nlazy\ndog.'`

another_var=$(printf '%s\n' And they lived happily ever after.)

yet_another=$'The\nend.'
```

The first method (literally typing <kbd>Enter</kbd> inside quotes)
should work in most, if not all, POSIX-compliant shells<sup>1</sup>. 
The second method
(`` `echo word1 ; echo word2` ``)
should work in most, if not all, POSIX-compliant shells<sup>2</sup>,
although the
`echo -e 'word3\nword4'`)
part might not. 
Some old shells might not recognize `$(…)`,
and the `$'…'` is (exclusively?) a bashism.

I deliberately used variable names without a consistent pattern
to demonstrate that the solution doesn’t depend on
the variable names following a pattern. 
You could use `varA`, `varB`, `varC` and `varD`
(or `var1`, `var2`, `var3` and `var4`) if you want.

Running the solution:

```
$ ./myscript1 "$var17" "$var42" "$another_var" "$yet_another"
The               jumps             And               The
quick             over              they              end.
brown             the               lived
fox               lazy              happily
                  dog.              ever
                                    after.
```

Note the obvious: the strings have different numbers of lines,
and the lines have different numbers of characters. 
We don’t *have to* use the variables;
we can put a multi-line string value directly on the command line:

```
$ ./myscript1 "$var17" "$var42" "$another_var"   $'The\nend.'
The               jumps             And               The
quick             over              they              end.
brown             the               lived
fox               lazy              happily
                  dog.              ever
                                    after.
```

Here’s `myscript1`:

```
#!/bin/dash
first=1
for a in "$@"
do
        if [ "$first" = 1 ]
        then
                set --
                first=
        fi
        file=`mktemp`
        set -- "$@" "$file"
        printf '%s\n' "$a" > "$file"
done
pr -T -m "$@"

rm "$@"
```

Notes:

- Since many POSIX-compliant shells do not have named arrays,
  we use the one (unnamed) array that they do all support: the argument list.
- Once we get into the `for a in "$@"` loop,
  ***its*** value list is set, so we can change the shell’s argument list.
- First time through, clobber the shell’s argument list with `set --`.
- Each time through,

  - Create a temporary file. 
    Use `` `mktemp` `` rather than `$(mktemp)` for increased portability
    (otherwise, `$(…)` is generally preferred).
  - Add the filename to the argument list.
  - Write the current argument
    (i.e., the multi-line string from the *original* argument list) to the file. 
    I don’t know whether `printf` is available
    as a builtin command in all shells,
    but it should be *available*
    (as either a builtin command or an external executable program)
    on all systems outside a museum. 
    If your system doesn’t have `printf`, you can try using `echo`,
    but beware strings that begin with **`-`** or contain `\`.
- Invoke `pr` on the list of files.

  - Use `-T`, as identified by steeldriver, to prevent pagination.
  - Use `-m` to merge the files (i.e., in multi-column mode).
- Finally, delete all the files.

This looks like it separates the columns by a lot of space,
but it doesn’t always:

```
$ ./myscript1 "A very long string about a quick brown fox and a lazy dog" .
A very long string about a quick br .
```

What’s happening is:

- `pr` counts the number of files; i.e., the number of columns. 
  Let’s call it *n.*
- It divides the line width by *n,* rounding down. 
  (The line width defaults to 72.)
- It creates *n* columns,
  each ⌊ 72/*n* ⌋ character positions wide. 
  Values narrower than that are padded; values wider than that are truncated.

You may prefer to avoid the blank space and the truncation. 
We can do this,
since we can specify the line width to `pr` with the `-w` option:

```
$ ./myscript2 "A very long string about a quick brown fox and a lazy dog" .
A very long string about a quick brown fox and a lazy dog  .
```

Here’s `myscript2`:

```
#!/bin/dash
if [ "$#" = 0 ]
then
        printf '%s\t%s\n' "Usage:" "$0 [string] ..."
        exit 1
fi
first=1
maxwidth=0
for a
do
        if [ "$first" = 1 ]
        then
                set --
                first=
        fi
        file=`mktemp`
        set -- "$@" "$file"
        printf '%s\n' "$a" > "$file"
        width=`printf '%s\n' "$a" | wc -L`
        if [ "$width" -gt "$maxwidth" ]
        then
                maxwidth="$width"
        fi
done
linewidth=`expr "$#" "*" "(" "$maxwidth" + 2 ")"`
pr -T -w "$linewidth" -m "$@"

rm "$@"
```

Notes:

- `for a` is short for `for a in "$@"`. 
  This works in ash, bash, dash, zsh, and probably others.
- `wc -L` finds the maximum line length in the input. 
  Unfortunately, this is a GNU extension. 
  This can be done using POSIX tools, but not as simply.
- The loop finds the longest line in any of the inputs …
- … and then we calculate a line width that’s enough
  to accommodate *n* columns of that width,
  plus two spaces for column separation.

____________ 
<sup>1</sup> But the C shell does not allow this
unless you type a <kbd>\</kbd> before the <kbd>Enter</kbd>. 
<sup>2</sup> The C shell allows this,
but it converts the newlines into spaces. 
(I’m probably missing something.)

Answer (score 0):

**1. Command `paste`**

```
paste /dev/fd/3 3<<-EOF /dev/fd/4 4<<-EOF
> $varA
> EOF
> $varB
> EOF
```

Output :

```
Aug 01  04:25
Aug 16  03:39
Aug 26  10:06
```

*alternative, you can use paste with temporary file too, but it lengthy process*
`temp_file=$(mktemp)`

---

**2. Command `pr`**

```
printf '%s\n' "$varA" "$varB" | pr -2 -t -s
```

Output:

```
Aug 01  04:25
Aug 16  03:39
Aug 26  10:06
```

Comment: This answer is partly correct, but it lacks detail and explanation.  Specifically, it doesn’t seem to honor the bounty comment: “The answer should work on all shells, for variables that do not have the same number of lines, and should work for a dynamic number of variables”.  (1) While it’s fairly obvious how to expand your `paste` solution to more than two variables, you should explain it.  (One sentence should be enough.) … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  And you should definitely point out that it might not work for more than seven variables, because not all shells understand `10<<`.  (And why do you use `<<-` instead of plain `<<`?)  And your comment about ``temp_file=$(mktemp)`` is almost totally useless to somebody who doesn’t already know how to do it. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (2) The `pr` solution is basically an uncredited copy of steeldriver’s answer, and, as steeldriver pointed out, it *does **not*** work correctly for variables that do not have the same number of lines.  And, if it were an original, correct answer, you should explain that the `-2` option should be adjusted to reflect the number of variables.   P.S.  There’s another solution using `pr` that ***does*** work correctly for variables that do not have the same number of lines — can you find it?

Comment: I just noticed that your `paste` answer looks strikingly like [Fritjof Larsson’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/639752/80216) to the question Stéphane Chazelas linked to.  Yes, you certainly could have developed it independently; I won’t accuse you of plagiarism.  But be aware that [SE] really dislikes plagiarism.  Please don’t copy somebody else’s work without identifying the source (ideally by name and link).   Even if somebody else’s work ***inspired*** your answer, you should acknowledge it.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' aww man.. Did you have a grudge with me ? so you stalk all my activity ? 
(1). Detail of command, it up to my time, I'm not nanny to describe every command. (2). it just today that i know Fritjof Larsson answer indentical to mine. I searching on google like 20 tabs to get there. (3). Even "thankyou" word not recomended here, so it not wrong to simple answer, if it work uset it, if not change other